# How to arrange an Epic in a Discord based community?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, online-roleplaying

After a few months organizing an Adventurers League in a Discord community, we are now discussing about the possibility of setting up an Epic session.

We know that it is supposed to be a live event, but is there a precedent of an online community holding an Epic?

**What do we need to prepare it?**

Can the Epic be held over the course of a few days (to account for people’s availability)?

Comment: Do you have a specific epic in mind (it may or may not be relevant, but so figured it's be worth asking)?

Comment: @DavidCoffron I'm not sure what epic is available (other guy is providing the content), but we are currently playing season 1 adventures. I'll ask them first, but I'm guessing season 1 epic.

Answer (score 1):

There are precedents of online conventions getting awarded EPICs. All you have to do is apply. Applications are awarded based on experience running conventions, so if you've never done you might want to run a single day/weekend online event. Running Epics requires some amount of coordination between tables so the AL admins want to make sure you have experience running multi-table events so players and DMs have a good experience.

From the [D&D Adventurers League convention page](http://dndadventurersleague.org/start-here/conventions/):

> D&D Epics Conventions (single- or multi-day) and store game days can
>   request a D&D Epic by filling out the [Request for Premiere, Epic, or
>   Regional Preview Adventure form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5scuqsfgaJTpQmcU5Wmi2hU79AgVVBn0PVHudn9tWbRb6hQ/viewform). D&D Epics are exciting multi-table
>   events where participants cooperate in a “mass raid” of truly EPIC
>   proportions; as every table works toward the same goal, individual
>   tables act as squads that might take on different tasks, possibly
>   affecting other tables or unlocking side quests needed to progress the
>   event.
>
> Each season’s D&D Epics have minimum table requirements, which events
>   must meet to offer the adventure.

Previously [ALOCon](https://www.facebook.com/ALO.Convention) was awarded an Epic and another online convention, but I can't find anything online about it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't

> Conventions (single- or multi-day) and store game days can request a D&D Epic

http://dndadventurersleague.org/start-here/conventions/

You are not a convention or a store. But you can still ask by filling the form. But I doubt it will work on Discord, because Epic are supposed to have interactions between tables that will be difficult to do on an online event. The Epic is supposed to be run in a limited amount of time no matter what, (including technical difficulties).

Beside, Epics event features a lot of tables interactions that I'm not sure will work with a Discord voice chat.